# IntelliJ Idea - how to disable properties substitution in spring config files?

Tags: intellij-idea

The spring config files replaces the property value in the IDE. If I hover over the value, then it shows the property name. Is there a way I can disable it Or I can use some shortcut to display property strings instead of the values.

For e.g., 
my config file has

```
<bean ...>
  <property name="appid" value="${test.appid}" />
</bean>
```

when I see it in IDE, it shows

```
<bean ...>
  <property name="appid" value="com.test.app" />
</bean>
```

with the value of property replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just code-folding for I18N strings. You can disable it in the settings, under ***Editor → Code Folding***:

[image: idea i18n code folding]